# FTP за NAT на нестандартном порту

Tags: linux, ftp, iptables, nat

Шлюз на Debian 7.11 (3.2.0-4-686-pae), iptables v1.4.14.

ip внешнего интерфейса: 1.1.1.1

ip внутреннго интерфейса: 192.168.1.1

Внутри локальной сети работает ftp-сервер, для которого нужно организовать доступ снаружи.

ip ftp-сервера во внутренней сети: 192.168.1.55

Порт ftp-сервера во внутренней сети: 51

Вывод lsmod | grep ftp

```bsh
nf_nat_ftp             12420  0
nf_conntrack_ftp       12533  2 nf_nat_ftp
nf_nat                 17913  2 iptable_nat,nf_nat_ftp
nf_conntrack           43121  9 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_nat,iptable_nat,xt_conntrack,xt_state,nf_conntrack_ftp,nf_nat_ftp,xt_CT,nf_conntrack_netlink
```

Вот так не работает:

```bsh
iptables -t raw -A PREROUTING --dst 1.1.1.1   -p tcp --dport 55555 -j CT --helper ftp
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ext --dst 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 55555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.55:51
```

Управляющее соединение открывается, но соденение для потока данных нет.
conntrack -E expect ничего не показывает.

Если переделать, чтобы порт ftp-сервер был стандартным (настройки ftp-сервера и настройки iptables), то все работает:

```bsh
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ext --dst 1.1.1.1 -p tcp --dport 55555 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.55:21
```

Подскажите пожалуйста какие нужны настройки, чтобы сделать доступным ftp-сервер, работающий на нестандартном порту?

Comment: а это точно все правила относящиеся к делу?

Comment: Есть еще правила фильтрации. Но она пока отключена.

Comment: Да, и в пробросе порта тоже соответственно меняем 21-й порт и 55555-й порт.

Comment: похоже `nf_conntrack_ftp` нужно порты, за которыми он будет следить в параметрах передавать: `modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp ports=51`

Comment: Тут говорят, что использование опций модуля является не рекомендуемым и устаревшим способом:

https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/

«iptables -A PREROUTING -t raw -p tcp --dport 2121 -d 1.2.3.4 -j CT --helper ftp

Therefore, the use of the module options is NOT recommended anymore – please use the CT target instead.»

Поэтому и захотел попробовать новый способ.